# Are duplicated NVARCHAR values stored as copies in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, azure-sql-database, slowly-changing-dimension

I'm designing a table that will contain a lot of rows. So need to be careful not to store to much information. One of the columns is a NVARCHAR(MAX) column and it contains the address of our customers. As addresses do not change often, this column will contain many repeated values and thus contains quite some redundancy.

So I was wondering if I need to normalize this myself by maintaining some sort of look-up table to address strings (note that if an address changes I need to maintain history - so it's not a matter of usual normalization), or if SQL Server is pointing to the same reference of the string behind the scenes. Or maybe it offers a column option to do so. Another approach that came into my mind is to use COMPRESS but I guess this does not make sense as the data itself (i.e. the address) is not long.

Reading/writing performance is not so much of a concern as the data will be accumulated over time.

Comment: An address is stored in a nvarchar(max) column? I think your design needs to be reconsidered. In addition, it is difficult to understand how different customers would have the same address (ignoring how they are stored).

Comment: @Smor forget about addresses. It just a (maybe misleading) example. My question is a general one: basically, are duplicated strings stored as copies or is there a way of enforcing this.

Comment: @SMor Sounds pretty reasonable to me; are you suggesting that the size is excessive, or that you'd try to normalise addresses into some kind of complex schema that would break for half the valid addresses people want to enter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes duplicated data is stored as copies in SQL Server

To change this behavior, you would need to implement PAGE COMPRESSION feature - create or rebuild indexes with (`data_compression = page`) option

It is a great feature that helps to save space. Once you enable it, SQL Server is pointing to the same reference of the string on the same page behind the scenes

Beware that PAGE COMPRESSION is not available in every SQL Server Edition, and it can have some CPU overhead

So you might want to make a lookup table if your edition does not allow for page compression

Answer (score 12):

Under "normal" conditions, no, data in `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` columns is not de-duped (although duplicate attribute and/or element names in a single `XML` value are reduced to a unique instance).

Using one of the Data Compression options is probably your best bet. Here are some things to consider:

1. [Unicode Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/unicode-compression-implementation) (part of Row Compression) only works on `NVARCHAR(1 - 4000)`, not `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (please vote for / support: [Unicode compression NVARCHAR(MAX)](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/53a479cb-7f25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)).
2. [Page Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/page-compression-implementation) can work with `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, but *only* for in-row data. Off-row data (LOB pages) is not compressed.

Since the data won't really be changing, you should look into the Columnstore Index options (also available in Azure SQL Database):

- [Columnstore indexes: Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview)
- [Columnstore indexes - Design guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance)

Columnstore compression should be better than Page compression.

Also, you should probably avoid using the `SPARSE` option, due to:

1. The `SPARSE` option offers no benefit compared to Data Compression.
2. It is mainly intended for columns sets / [wide tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/tables#wide-tables) (i.e. up to 30,000 columns).
3. It mostly helps with *fixed-length* datatypes (e.g. `INT`, `DATETIME`). So, prior to Data Compression being available, it was useful for `CHAR` and `NCHAR`, but not for `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` as they don't take up space when `NULL`.
4. It only benefits columns set to `NULL`.
5. It slightly hurts non-`NULL` values by adding 2 bytes to each one.
6. You should probably have `NULL` for 50% - 60% of the rows in order to get enough savings for it to be worth using this option.

For more details on working with character data, please see the following post of mine:

[How Many Bytes Per Character in SQL Server: a Completely Complete Guide](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/11/22/how-many-bytes-per-character-in-sql-server-a-completely-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 6):

Compression is fine and probably useful in your case, but you should normalize your tables anyway and try to achieve a structure where you're only storing one copy of the same address. This will lead to less redundancy, and lighten the primary table you're currently asking about.

Another two things to consider too are:

1. NVARCHAR can use twice as much space as a VARCHAR of equally used length (Solomon Rutzky's answer links a good article regarding this), so it can be more data heavy. If you can use VARCHAR instead, you can probably drop the length down to something much more reasonable for an address field and save a lot more space. Here's an article comparing the two: [SQL varchar data type deep dive](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-varchar-data-type-deep-dive/#:%7E:text=The%20key%20difference%20between%20varchar,the%20space%20as%20SQL%20varchar.)
2. You should also look into sparse columns which can save you a significant amount of space too when used correctly. Here's the Microsoft docs: [Use Sparse Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver15)

   (Important to note that a minimum amount of NULL values need to be present for sparse columns to be worth looking into.)

Comment: Note that with compression NVARCHAR uses Unicode Compression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/unicode-compression-implementation?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft and J.D.: please note that `NVARCHAR(MAX)` won't use Unicode Compression. That only applies to `NVARCHAR(1 - 4000)` and `NCHAR(1 - 4000`)`.

Comment: J.D.: While good advice to normalize, the two points to consider are both incorrect: 1) `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` do not pre-allocate / reserve space. Only `CHAR` and `NCHAR` take up the full declared size of the column, even if mostly or entirely unused. 2) `SPARSE` columns don't really help much with variable-length datatypes. And, since they only help when the column is set to `NULL`, yet hurt when non-`NULL` (taking up 2 extra bytes), that would appear to be a step in the wrong direction given the use-case here implies there are few, if any, `NULL`s. (-1)

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Fair enough on pre-allocation, but still valid that VARCHAR will take up half the space as NVARCHAR for the same length of data. Good point on the unicode compression, though I think for an Address field, OP probably could scale the length down to 4,000 or less - but that's up to him to decide. Regarding sparse columns, I was only offering it up as informational with the "when used correctly" clause, and the docs I linked discuss when and how to use them effectively (even if OP found use for his other columns). Though I wouldn't infer how many NULLs his whole schema has.

Comment: J.D.: Yes, `VARCHAR` would be a good option if it would not lead to data loss, depending on what needs to be stored. And yes, I would hope that an address could fit within 8000 bytes (whether `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`), so once again better modeling is the place to start :-). And yes, I did notice (and do appreciate) that you had the "when used correctly" qualification, but I'm still not sure it's something that should be mentioned in this context. However, if you simply remove "and it's pre-allocated", and change "reserves" to "uses" then I will remove the -1 (as they're the reason for it).

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Done and done, thanks for reminding me about being able to improve my answer. You're a good man Charlie Brown!

Comment: @J.D. No problem, and thank you for making that improvement. My concern was / is that so many readers are in a hurry to find an answer and don't read comment, and there's already so much misinformation floating around. I feel we should, as much as possible, try to decrease, rather than increase, the amount of confusion caused by erroneous info. So I really do appreciate you taking the time to make those changes  (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Just a note on page compression: This type of compression is limited on what's on a page. I.e., you won't see any reduction of duplicates values that ends up on different pages.

Also, page compression was made available in lower editions as of SQL Server 2016 sp1; and from what I can see this also applies to Azure SQL Database according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/features-comparison).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of your design, but my recommendation is that you store the address in a separate table from the customer table. The association between the two tables will depend on the business logic (e.g. is an address associated with one or many customers). My experience of putting an entire address in one column makes it more difficult; for example, finding all customers in a state or country involves a substring search.

The other advantages are that maintaining address history is much simpler (you can have a revision number in the address table or link table), validity date range, and you can manage security more efficiently.

From a performance point view, large columns make for bloated rows. Bloated rows can reduce the performance; for example, fewer rows can be transferred per I/O operation.  The definition of bloated varies on which DBMS you use, how it is configured, the OS, etc. I try to keep my table rows less than 8K in size, which well within the performance envelope.

Answer (score 0):

Aleksey has answered your question very well - however I'm not entirely sure what your end goal is.

If you have a very limited amount of space to store this database then compression will help with this - but compressing strings (such as an address) will net you a very small amount of space saved in modern terms.

You've alluded to there being repeated data for your customers - if I were to guess I'd say it looks like you're creating some sort of transaction log for purchase/transactions? In that case, you would likely entirely omit the customers information from this table and simple use a reference to your customers' table object on each row, with a possible "override" for columns indicating something was non-standard about an order/transaction (like the customer used a difference address from their default).

I appreciate you may have security concerns however there may be better, more specific answers to your problem if you can provide more information on what you're trying to achieve. As it stands Aleksey has described one feature you asked about very well - whether that's the best feature for you isn't guaranteed.